# MySQL group by help simple example sql noob

Tags: mysql, group-by

The Query

```
select incident.incidentID,
GROUP_CONCAT(moccode2.Description) as MOC2Description 
from incident
join incidentmoc on incident.IncidentID = incidentmoc.IncidentID
inner join moccode2 on moccode2.id = incidentmoc.moccodeid
where incident.IncidentID=962
group by moccode2.Description
```

The results:

```
incidentID, MOC2Description
962, Therapist
962, Obscentiy
```

What I'm shooting for

```
incidentID, MOC2Description
962, Therapist, Obscentiy
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to group on `incident.incidentID` instead.